# Using UPDATE JOIN and database parameter

Tags: mysql, sql, join, pdo, parameters

How can i write this code?

```
$sorgu=$dbpdo->query("SELECT * FROM denetci_mahalle");


for ($i=0; $sorgu->rowCount(); $i++)
{
    $isletme=$dbpdo->prepare("
    UPDATE isletmeler
    JOIN denetci_mahalle
    ON isletmeler.adresi like '%'+@denetci_mahalle.mahalle+'%'
    SET isletmeler.sorumlu = denetci_mahalle.denetci
    ");
    $isletme->execute();

}
```

in this code `'%'+@denetci_mahalle.mahalle+'%'` is true? Pls help me.

Comment: `LIKE CONCAT('%', denetci_mahalle.mahalle, '%')`

Comment: i tried this. it isnt working.

Comment: this is the error code;  `Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded in C:\wamp\www\1.1.1\Web\ayarlar\guncelleme.php on line 225`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`+`  is not for concatenate string in PHP  if you need you could use . or better concat  .. and you con'y use @denetci_mahalle.mahall you hane not assign

you should  use the result for $sorgu

```
$sorgu=$dbpdo->query("SELECT * FROM denetci_mahalle");
 foreach ($sorgu  as $row) {

          $isletme=$dbpdo->prepare("
              UPDATE isletmeler
              JOIN denetci_mahalle
              ON isletmeler.adresi like concat('%','"  . $row['mahalle'] . "','%')  
              SET isletmeler.sorumlu = denetci_mahalle.denetci
              ");

       $isletme->execute();

  }
```

anyway you could avoid the foreach  just using

```
   $isletme=$dbpdo->prepare("
              UPDATE isletmeler a
              JOIN denetci_mahalle  b 
              ON a.adresi like concat('%',  b.mahalle ,'%')  
              SET a.sorumlu = b.denetci
              ");
    $isletme->execute();
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. This code throw this error: `Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Mahalle' in 'on clause' in C:\wamp...`

Comment: asnwer  updated add single quote around the var  $row['mahalle'] .. otherwise sql use the result as a column name

Comment: Thank you for your help. It is worked when i dont use for or foreach.

Answer (score 0):

No need for cursors and a loop.  You can do this in one query:

```
UPDATE isletmeler i JOIN
       denetci_mahalle m
       ON i.adresi like concat('%', d.mahalle, '%')
    SET i.sorumlu = d.denetci;
```

The outer select is not needed.